# Which player will hold the ball, passing it clockwise as per square number series

Tags: sequences-and-series, divisibility

There are 10 persons, having jersey number marked as 0, 1, 2,.....,9. They are standing in a circular arrangement, as shown in figure:
[image]

In a game, they are passing ball **clockwise** in the following way:

The game starts with the **0 marked** player holding the ball.

After the end of **1st round**, the ball is passed $1^2 = 1$ times,
 i.e. the ball ends up at the **1 marked** player.

At the end of **2nd round** the ball is further passed $2^2 = 4$ times, so the ball ends up at the **5 marked** player

At the end of **3rd round** the ball is further passed $3^2 = 9$ times, i.e. the ball ends up at the **4 marked** player.

**Question is:-**

which player will hold the ball, at the end of **2018th** round ?

In solution, 
I expressed the square of every natural number, according to divisibility by 10.
Thus, summing them up, I found that the answer should be the **9 marked player**

Isn't it correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$9$ looks right.

You can get by a little quicker than summing 2018 squares by using one (or both) of two tricks:

**First**, find or derive a formula for the sum of the $n$ first squares, and plug $2018$ into that. (I don't go around remembering the formula, but I know it's a cubic polynomial, and I can derive the coefficients by fitting a cubic to the known values $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, $f(2)=5$, $f(3)=14$).

**Second**, each group of $100$ successive rounds leave the ball at its original position -- because only the last digit of each round number matters for its movement, and after $100$ round each digit will have appeared $10$ times, so its sums cancel each other out modulo $10$.

Therefore you actually only need to sum the squares for the first $18$ rounds -- the remaining $2000$ rounds split into groups of $100$ and therefore have no net effect.

Comment: The sum of the first $n$ squares is $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a typo in your answer but your approach is perfectly fine.

We have $$\sum_{i=1}^{2018} i^2 \pmod {10} \equiv 9$$ not $0$. Try to prove the fact. Hope it helps.